# Rearrange string k distance Apart - Proof

Tags: greedy, proof

Problem:
Given a non-empty string str of length l and an integer k, rearrange
the string such that the same characters are at least distance k from
each other. In case, it is not possible to do it with length l, you
can insert empty spaces and return the permutation with minimum empty
spaces.

E.x.
str = "aabbcc", k = 3

Result: "abcabc"

The greedy idea is:

1) Sort the characters by frequencies and take the highest frequency
character for first place. Take the next available highest frequency
character for second place and so on...

E.x. for "aabbcc", k = 3
(character, freq)
(a,2)
(b,2)
(c,2)

Pick a. then pick b, then pick c, pick a, pick b, pick c

How can we prove this?

Answer (score 0):

We can think of the situation when we can't choose any character, and that's when the kinds of characters is less than k but we still have characters that have a frequency higher than 1. The best way to avoid this situation is clearly always choosing the character with the highest frequency.